# Eclipse oxygen - package explorer empty

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I just installed

```
Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0)
Build id: 20170620-1800
```

I have a view like in the screenshot. When I try to open or import a project, it says project already exists. And yet I do not see in in package explorer, it is empty.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change **Top Level Elements** view menu. Change it to "Projects" if you don't have **workings sets** created. See [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/platform.php#project-explorer-others-working-set).